# Embed videos on Facebook with a Timeline-enabled profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video-streaming, facebook-timeline

I'm trying to correctly implement the Open Graph tags for Facebook on a video site, using the og:video tags.

Example : http://12-infos.nrj12.fr/videos-3738/media/video/481196-mardi-6-decembre-mamie-est-une-lumiere.html

It works perfectly on a "normal" account (the video is correctly shared, and can be read from Facebook with ou SWF player, or via iPhone apps with the MP4).

When I use a timeline-enabled account, a click on the image/title just redirects me on the page without opening the player ?!

Is there something more to do to make embed videos working with timeline accounts ?

Thank you

Comment: I have an account that has not been upgraded to the timeline, and when I click the link, it opens a new window.  I tried with an account that has timeline, and again, when I click the link, it opens a new window.  I'm not sure how to reproduce.  Can you provide clearer instructions on how to make it play inline with an account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>As Hamed Hashemi said your player and video has to have a https links when viewed from https enabled accounts. I had this problem last week and to achieve this I just edit the links to always have https protocol. That way you'll be sure that they are visible from http and https from within the FB page.</strike>

Correction: You don't have one og meta tag and that's og:video:secure_url. This is the https URL. So basically you'll have 2 urls leading to the video: one http and ope https. Than facebook will which one show when. Add this url and try it again.

Take a look here: http://ogp.me/#structured

Answer (score 1):

make sure if you are on https version of facebook that the swf file is hosted via https as well